HTTP Post not working after Tomcat update
There is an application which transfers file from source to destination and post file transfer, it sends a post message (SOAP) to another application sending the status of File transfer. Everything was fine till Tomcat 8.5.
We upgraded recently to Tomcat 10. After this upgrade, File transfer process works well and this POST is broken. Error message is,

The Header Line [POST http://xxx.yyy.com:8080/axis2/services/TestService.Endpoint/ HTTP/1.1] does not conform to RFC7230 and has been ignored.

I searched this error and added few properties to the HTTP Connector.

rejectIllegalHeader=false

encodedSolidusHandling=passthrough


After adding these properties, I got a new error:

HTTP Status 400 - Bad Error.

I tried a few things, but nothing seems to be working. Any advise on how can I fix this error. I've mentioned both request and response below.
Request:
POST http://xxx.yyy.com:8080/axis2/services/TestService.Endpoint/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "sendStatus"
host:xxx.yyy.com:8080
Connection:Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Authorization: Basic <auth_key>

<soapenv>
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<xsd:status>
<xsd:filecount>2</xsd:filecount>
<xsd:fileextension>csv </xsd:fileextension>
</xsd:status>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv>

Response:
HTTPStatusCode : 400
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 765
Date:
Connection: close


<!doctype html>
<html>....HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request .....The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be client error .. </html>


There is a significant breaking API change from Tomcat 9 to 10, see Migrating from 9.0.x to 10.0.x: The Java package used by the specification APIs has changed from javax... to jakarta.... Did you update your code?
